# What is the bottle neck in using a DBContext?

Tags: performance, entity-framework-6

In the following code snippet, which ever List I load first takes about 3000 milliseconds more than the others.
This causes me to think that something is happening on the first .ToList() that it isn't happening on later .ToList() calls.  What could it be?

I am hoping there is something I can tweek to increase performance.

db is my DBContext instance.

> using (var db = new MyDataEntities())
>
> {
>
> ```
>             const int linkTypeId = 3;
>
>             var sw = new Stopwatch();
>             sw.Start();
>
>
>             // section A
>             sw.Restart();
>             var qry2 = from p in db.ViewPropertyPairs where p.LinkID == JobId && p.LinkType == linkTypeId select p;
>             this.ViewPropertyPairs = qry2.ToList();
>             sw.Stop();
>             Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}  ms for to view property pair list", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
>
>             // Section B
>
>             sw.Restart();
>             this.PropertyNames = db.PropertyNames.ToList();
>             sw.Stop();
>             Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}  ms for propertynames",  sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
>
>
>             // Section C
>             sw.Restart();
>             var qry =from p in db.PropertyPairs where p.LinkID == JobId && p.LinkType == linkTypeId select p ;
>             this.PropertyPairs = qry.ToList();
>             sw.Stop();
>             Debug.Print(string.Format("{0}  ms for to property pair list", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
>
>
>         }
> ```

Comment: Is it the very first query to database performed by your application? In such case it is initialization of EF infrastructure.

Comment: Thats it. thank you. Can you add it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first query (or `SaveChanges` call) in your application causes EF to initialize. There are some options to improve performance for this step (for example pre-compiling "views") but it will always be significantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

As Ladislav said, the first query is slower because of EF initialization. 
That said, you can force EF to initialize at the start of your application by calling the following code when your application starts.

```
using (var db = new MyDataEntities()) {
    context.Database.Initialize(force: true);
}
```

Is just a matter of **when** you want it to happen, at the start of your application or during the first Query/SaveChanges it makes.